# Regular Expression - start and end pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have  string as below in a file and would like to find each occurrences of string based on start and end pattern.

***STX=ANAA:1+5013546100993+5033075994542LI0927030002+5033075994542'MTR=3'END=4'STX=ANAA:1+5013546100993+5033075994542:1:D:068::288:10941/101'OTR=8'MTR=53'END=7'UNA:+.? 'DNB=1'MTR=3'END=5''STX=ANAA:1+5013546100893+5033075994542:1:D:068::288:10941/101''OTR=8''MTR=53''END=9***

I would like to find string which match the pattern starts with either STX Or UNA and end before start of the next segment of STX or UNA.

FOr the string above I would like to pull as below

1) STX=ANAA:1+5013546100993+5033075994542LI0927030002+5033075994542'MTR=3'END=4'

2) UNA:+.? 'DNB=1'MTR=3'END=5''

3) STX=ANAA:1+5013546100893+5033075994542:1:D:068::288:10941/101''OTR=8''MTR=53''END=9

I have written my regular expression as below

```
string pattern  = "(STX|UNA.*)STX|UNA"
```

But it always return the first match.

regards,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex captures the start of the next match. You should exclude it:

[`(STX|UNA).*?(?=(STX|UNA|$))`](http://regexr.com/3cjl2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your regex to do a non-greedy match. BTW your regex must be,

```
(STX|UNA).*?(STX|UNA)
```

`(STX|UNA.*)` in your regex would match `STX` or `UNA` plus zero or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex in c#

```
string strRegex = @"((STX)[^""""""""]*END=[0-9])('STX)|((UNA:+.?)[^""""""""]*END=[0-9]'')|((STX)[^""""""""]*END=[0-9])";
```

It have seven matches 1,4,6 are your expected matches,try it